# Populate array with resource images

Tags: vb.net, arrays, image

I'm trying to make a Blackjack game in VB.  What I'd like to do is populate an array with each of the cards so that I can randomly generate integers and use those integers to pull an index from the array, basically randomly selecting a card.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the images in the resources folder to go into the array. I'd like to use a For/Next loop to populate the array, as I would rather not manually assign all 52 cards to the array. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
Dim CardArray(51) As Image
Dim LoopIndexInteger As Integer

For LoopIndexInteger = 0 To 51
CardArray(LoopIndexInteger) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(LoopIndexInteger)
    Next
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetObject` takes a resource name, not an index.
You need to construct the name of one of your resources.

The simplest way to do that is to name the resources `Card0` through `Card51` and call `GetObject("Card" & CInt(LoopIndexInteger))`

**EDIT**: You can also loop over `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true)`, but it may not be in order.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid renaming the resources.  right now, they're named h7 (7 of hearts) and d1 (ace of diamonds) etc.. this way I can tell which card is which by looking at the file name.  If I rename them Card0-51 I'll have no way of knowing which card is which so I'll have no way of comparing the values later on to determine the winner of the hand. I see there's a method called 'Magic number' that holds the number used to identify resource files..could I somehow use this instead?

Comment: @Kris: You're misunderstanding magic numbers; they have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Well that's no good! haha. I may rename the resources as you suggested, but put them into a 2 dimensional array along with the card's rank/value.  Thank you for the pointers..I've been working on this for most of the day and it's driving me nuts! At least I have some direction to head in!